# Get url minus current filename in JSP or CQ5

Tags: java, jsp, aem

I wish to get the current url minus the file name that is being currently referenced. Whether the solution is in JSP or CQ5 doesn't matter. However, I am trying to use the latter more to get used to it.

I'm using this documentation but it's not helping. [CQ5 Docs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-3/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/PageManager.html).
The example I found retrieves the full current path, but I don't know how to strip the file name from it:

```
<% Page containingPage = pageManager.getContainingPage(resourceResolver.getResource(currentNode.getPath()));
%>
<a href="<%=containingPage.getPath() %>.html">Profile</a>
```

Comment: could you specify the reason to get only the path minus file name?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know anything about CQ5, but since `getPath()` returns an ordinary Java string I expect you could just take the prefix up to the last slash, which for a string `s` can be done with `s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf('/')+1)`. If you have to make it into a one-liner, you could do `containingPage.getPath().substring(0, containingPage.getPath().lastIndexOf('/')+1)`.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm learning Java by having to dive into the deep end first, so my grasp of certain fundamentals like this are lost.

Comment: Not a good solution when dealing with CQ5 (or Sling in general) - some use cases (especially image references come to mind) where the "file part" can actually include slashes.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are accessing the following resource URL.

/content/mywebsite/english/mynode

if your current node is "mynode" and you want to get the part of url without your current node.

then the simplest way to do is, call getParent() on currentNode(mynode)

therefore, you can get the path of your parent like this.

**currentNode.getParent().getPath()** will give you **"/content/mywebsite/english/"**

full code :

```
    <% Page containingPage = pageManager.getContainingPage(resourceResolver.getResource(currentNode.getParent().getPath())); 
%>
<a href="<%=containingPage.getPath() %>.html">Profile</a>
```

Comment: A slightly more refined answer than the first. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

A much simpler approach.

You can use the currentPage object to get the parent Page.

The code looks like this

```
<a href="<%=currentPage.getParent().getPath()%>.html">Profile</a>
```

In case you are getting an error while using this code, check whether you have included the global.jsp file in the page. The one shown below.

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
```

Comment: I do have the global include. As for your shortcut, I still have to instantiate currentPage; what is that initial value?

Comment: if you have already included global.jsp, then you wont need to instantiate currentPage. currentPage is an implicit object, you will get it automatically when you include global.jsp and its default value is the current page object.

Comment: Yes, as rao_555 pointed out, if you have global.jsp included in the JSP file where you are using this piece of code, then you need not instantiate it again. currentPage object contains handle to the webpage you are currently being served.